# Restrict Blazor component usage

Tags: blazor

Is it possible to restrict the use of a Blazor component? I don't want it to show up in the list when you are typing in Visual Studio.

If I for instance make an icon component.
It contains a parameter which is a Renderfragment.

Then I create a IconArrow component which has the icon component inside it.

```
<Icon>
//Ex SVG with an Arrow
</Icon>
```

As of now I have it in a different folder which makes it so that it doesn't show up when you start tying but if you add a using you can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported.

But in the frameworks I make I limit its usage, which will throw an exception at runtime. This can be done using Cascading Parameters:

Parent:

```
<div>
    <CascadingValue Value="this" Name="IconParent">
        <Icon />
    </CascadingValue>
</div>
```

Child:

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "IconParent")]
    public IconParentComponent Parent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The component \"Icon\" can only be using within a pre-defined component");
    }
}
```